# qtcreator: file not found in certain condition

Tags: linux, qt

I came across a strange problem when I compiled program in QtCreator2.4.1. (Qt 4.8.1, Ubuntu 12.04)

As long as I create a project and choose *Qt4.8.1 in PATH(System) **debug*** option, then add following phrase in .pro file(the file is already on site, it's a third-party lib):

`LIBS += -L./lib -lHCNetSDK.lib`(no matter it's `LIBS += -L./lib -lHCNetSDK` or `LIBS += -L./lib HCNetSDK.lib`)

I will get `file not found` error. If I choose **release** then no problem at all but then I can't debug. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clarify your issue a bit. Maybe some confusion with target `debug` / `release` folders? Do you use shadow build?

Comment: @dvvrd Yeah, I used shadow build. So it's like, when I choose **debug** mode to build a project, this error occurs while when it's **release** mode, there're no such errors. (And I can use various writing style to add .lib file  in .pro)